# Why do a timezone-unaware and a timezone-aware datetime object with a different timezone yield the same unix-timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp, utc

So, as far as I understand if you convert without a timezone from or to a unix-timestamp you will always get GMT/UTC, like this:

```
import datetime
import pytz
datetime.datetime(2020,4,1,0,0,0).timestamp()
```

The resulting timestamp is `1585692000`.

Now if I do this:

```
(pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin").localize(datetime.datetime(2020,4,1,0,0,0))).timestamp()
```

It yields the same unix-timestamp.

If I enter a datetime and tell the program that this datetime has the timezone GMT+1 then its UTC value should be offset by 1 hour, and since a unix-timestamp is always UTC it should be different as well, but it's the same.

Why? Which of my assumptions is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNIX timestamps have no timezone, they always express the number of seconds elapsed since Jan. 1st 1970 00:00 UTC. That number is the same globally, it doesn't change with your timezone.

> Naive `datetime` instances are assumed to represent local time and [`timestamp`] relies on the platform C `mktime()` function to perform the conversion.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

So, if you are in Europe/Berlin, then a naïve `datetime` and a `datetime` localised to Europe/Berlin are interpreted the same way when converted to a timestamp. Try localising to other timezones, which means that `2020, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0` *actually* refers to a different time, and you'll see different timestamps as well.